# How to call function which has sys_refcursor as in parameter?

Tags: c#, oracle11g

There is the function that has a `sys_refcursor` as an `IN` argument. I use this function for insert multiple records in a table.
I have two tables Err,Err2:

```
CREATE TABLE "Err" ("code" NUMBER(20) NOT NULL ,"msg" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) NULL 

CREATE TABLE "Err2" ("code" NUMBER(20) NOT NULL ,"msg" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) NULL
```

and i use the following code to copy records from `Err` to  `Err2`

```
        OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "begin open :1 for  select * from \"Err\" ; end;";
        OracleParameter outcur = cmd.Parameters.Add("outcur", OracleDbType.RefCursor, DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.Output);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.CommandText ="RegisterErrCollection";

        cmd.BindByName = true;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_ErrCollection", OracleDbType.RefCursor, outcur.Value, ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("return_value", OracleDbType.Int32, DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It returns an refcursor as an output and passes to this function as a `IN` parameter:

```
FUNCTION RegisterErrCollection(P_ERRCOLLECTION IN SYS_REFCURSOR)  RETURN NUMBER AS
Contrac_rc "Err"%rowtype;
BEGIN
  Loop
 Fetch P_ERRCOLLECTION Into Contrac_rc;
  EXIT WHEN P_ERRCOLLECTION%NOTFOUND;
   Insert into "Err2"("code","msg")
   Values(Contrac_rc."code",Contrac_rc."msg");
 End Loop;
  RETURN 1;
END;
```

Yes It works well! 
But i want to call the function with new data instead of `Err` records. I think i have to convert my data (it's placed in `DataTable` or `List<ErrObject>`) to OracleRefCursor.
Now, How to instantiate an `OracleRefCursor` with my own data?(something like an `DataTable`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relatively simple trick to accomplish this: instead of selecting from table `Err`, you select from `dual` and dynamically build your select statement.

Something like this for your first command:

```
cmd.CommandText =
    "begin" +
    "    open :1 for" +
    "        select 1 code, 'Message1' msg from dual" +
    "        union" +
    "        select 2, 'Message2' from dual" +
    "        union" +
    "        select 3, 'Message3' from dual"
    "end;";
```

This gives you a cursor with the data you specified that you can then use as a parameter in your `RegisterErrCollection` function. It's of course easy to replace `1`, `2`, `3` and `Message1`,  `Message2`, `Message3` with your own data or to specify less or more messages.

As far as I know there is no way to directly use a `DataTable` or list of data as `sys_refcursor` input parameter.